# how to get a variable's definition file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find the original definition declaration of a variable.

What linux commands or actions will output environment variable's source definition file and all files that have changed that variable?

Is there a way to trace the bin bash command echo down to it's source in BASH?

How does echo work in bash?  Where is echo getting the value for a variable?

Comment: You ask a lot of different questions here. What specific `echo` variable are you concerned with? Do you want to look at the source code for `echo`? Want to have verbose output in BASH while interpreting? Then use `set -x` and `set +x` and `set` to list vars.

Comment: I want to see the file name of the source definition of any variable.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to dig?

Comment: Did that;  it isn't what I'm after.

Comment: Please, one question per question. There is no limit to how many questions you can ask -- ask a separate one for each question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bash doesn't keep track of what line of what file set a given variable, and it would be terribly inefficient if it did so. But you can debug bash scripts using the `-x` flag.

See: [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

Comment: +1 Environment variables are simply an array of `char*` pointers, each one containing a pointer to a string `variable=value`. There is no facility for auditing which process changed which value. You would need to implement your own kernel functions and probably recompile most of the user-space binaries as well to change that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a variable is a variable and contains no information on what defined it.
A possible workaround is to search inside files with grep, from your home directory or / (this may take a while):

`grep -r "VARIABLE" * 2> /dev/null`